# Testing a Complicated sort feature with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, testing, jasmine

I'm learning [Jasmine](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery), and I am trying to test a complicated sort feature. Essentially, when the ('.overview_table_header') class is clicked, $(this) is populated with the name of the column, from a list of columns: Likes, Checkins, State, etc.

Say "Likes" is selected. It would then sort the likes column, sending a GET request to the server. I would like to test this process in Jasmine and I do not know where to even begin. How would you write a test? I'll show you what I have so far.

**Javascript to be tested:**

```
$('.overview_table_header').click(function() {
  header = $(this);
  var col2 = $.trim($(this).text());
  var sort2 = header.data('sort');
  $.get("/search", { promotion_id: $("input[name=promotion_id]").val(), chag_col: $.trim($(this).text()), chag_sort: header.data('sort'), page: 1, q:$("input[name=q]").val(), etime: $("input[name=etime]").val(), stime: $("input[name=stime]").val() },
    function(data) {
      $('#pages').html(data.html);
      $('#pagelink').html(data.page_links);
      header.data('sort', data.sort);
      if (data.sort == 'ASC') {
        arrow = '<';
      }
      else {
        arrow = '>';
      }
      $('span.arrow').html('');
      header.siblings('.arrow').html(arrow);
      $("input[name=chag_sort]").val(sort2);
      $("input[name=chag_col]").val(col2);
      console.log(data.sort);
    }
  );
});
```

**My Jasmine Test:**

```
describe("Sort Feature", function() {
  it("sorts columns of data based on user clicks", funciton(){
     loadFixtures("home.html");

     $(".overview_table_header")
  });
});
```

**My Fixture**

```
<table>
      <thead>

        <tr>
          <th class='col_1'>
            <span class='overview_table_header'>Total Checkins</span>
          </th>
          <th class='col_2'>
            <span class='overview_table_header'>Trending Place</span>
          </th>
          <th class='col_3'>

            <span class='overview_table_header'>Top Place</span>
          </th>
          <th class='col_4'>
            <span class='overview_table_header'>Top State</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Jasmine is DOM agnostic. You can write scripts that access jQuery elements in Jasmine, but it would be easier to use jasmine-jquery.

jasmine-jquery extends the Jasmine framework with a robust set of methods to handle HTML fixtures.

This makes it easier to write scripts that access jQuery, for example:

```
describe('test with jasmine-jquery', function () {
  it('should load many fixtures into DOM', function () {
    loadFixtures('my_fixture_1.html', 'my_fixture_2.html');
    expect($('#jasmine-fixtures')).toSomething();
  });

  it('should only return fixture', function () {
    var fixture = readFixtures('my_fixture_3.html');
    expect(fixture).toSomethingElse();
  });
});
```

The GitHub page for jasmine-jquery is https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery

Simply download jasmine-jquery.js from the downloads page and include it in your Jasmine's test runner file. You must also include the jQuery library.

There is documentation on GitHub page. Once you install the library, just write an event spy:

> spyOnEvent($('#some_element'), 'click'); $('#some_element').click();
>   expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn($('#some_element'));